# Turkish character support in selectize filter is problematic

Tags: javascript

When filtering options in Selectize, words with Turkish characters such as "İ" (capital i with a dot) in the beginning like "İzmir", "İstanbul", "Uşak", and "Isparta" are not recognized properly. How can I solve this issue?

I tried many options but I couldn't do it.

Comment: Please provide the options you've tried or a working code snippet. Also, explain what the issue is properly.